# Coq simpl failing to do beta reduction in this fixpoint expression

Tags: coq, fixpoint

I have

```
Fixpoint concat_aux {A : Type} (lang1 lang2 : list A -> nat -> nat -> bool) (w : list A) (start : nat) (delta i : nat) : bool :=
    match lang1 w start i && lang2 w (start + i) (delta - i) with
    | true => true
    | false => match i with
        | 0 => false
        | S i' => concat_aux lang1 lang2 w start delta i'
        end
    end.
```

This lemma should be trivial by substituting,

```
Lemma concat_aux_correct1 {A : Type} : forall lang1 lang2 w start delta i,
    lang1 w start i = true /\ lang2 w (start + i) (delta - i) = true
    -> @concat_aux A lang1 lang2 w start delta i = true.
```

But the following fails to make progress.

```
Proof.
    intros.
    simpl. (* nothing happens *)
    unfold concat_aux.
    simpl. (* nothing happens *)
Admitted.
```

Why is this happening and what do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reduction to be done, which is why `simpl` isn't doing anything.

First of all, `concat_aux` is not a double fixpoint, but a simple fixpoint on the 7th argument `i` (as you can check from Coq's message upon going through the definition: `concat_aux is recursively defined (guarded on 7th argument)`). This means that reduction is only possible when the 7th argument is a constructor, i.e., either `O` or `S j` for some `j`, which is not the case.

Second of all, having an equality in your context is not enough to reduce anything. Compare

```
Eval simpl in (0 + 1).
```

with

```
Variable n : nat. Hypothesis H : n = 0.
Eval simpl in (n + 1).
```

The former reduces to `1`, while the latter stays the same.

Given the above, the way to make progress with your lemma is to do case analysis on `i` and then use your hypothesis about `lang1` and `lang2` being `true` to solve the goals. The case analysis is spurious, yes, but it will actually allow you to make progress. You can use the same proof for both cases (with copy-paste, `;`, goal selectors, a lemma, etc).

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks! Removed the part saying "double fixpoint"